# Excel - Copy if values are present in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with a couple of excel files.
I feel like this could be easily achieved but don't know how.

The File A have 2 columns:
Country and Name
Country is a lists of countries and there are duplicates.
Name is a list of person, there are duplicates here too but not within the same country.
So every couple Country - Name is unique

The File B is a reference file:
It only has a single instance of every
couple Country - Name and also a third column with an ID

What I'm trying to achieve is to compare the whole File A with the whole File B and if a correspondece is found, copy the right ID in a third column in File A

Comment: It's best to provide a simple sample file or some screenshots.

Comment: Your files need helper columnsn, then a `VLOOKUP` will work. If desired wrap that with `IFNA`

Answer (score 0):

What you wish to do is easy, so things are looking up already.

File A has two columns, Country and Name. I'll call them `A-Country` and `A-Name`. As an example, say one Country is "France" and one Name is "Picard."
File B has two columns, Country and Name, which I'll call `B-Country` and `B-Name` plus a third column, ID, which I'll still call `B-ID` to follow the pattern.

You want to do a lookup on the File B data. The "how" is the unusual part. But first, an ambiguity exists in what you say:  You say File A's Country+Name lines are unique, that while a Country may occur more than once, it will have different names and the same goes the other way, so that there are no duplicates of the combinations. You then state the same thing exists for File B, that all its combinations are unique. The ambiguity is that you say the File B part in a way that suggests that list is shorter than File A's because it is purer, carrying the suggestion that maybe File A DOES have duplications of the combinations. For example, rather than just one combination of "France+Picard" there might be 30 while in File B, there would definitely only be one such line. That's a problem because if one misunderstands and some other meaning is meant, but not that File A's list is as "pure" as File B's, it could matter. If the way I take the ambiguity, either it's the way I wrote above, OR it is precisely as "pure" as File B's list, and consequently, it doesn't matter to my answer. But if there IS an ambiguity that makes File A's status not as "pure" but for some other reason it may matter. As someone, somewhere, once said, "You are warned."

So. Honestly, I didn't feel like setting up two files and creating the formulas. So I've used the range A1:B10 for File A's Country and Name data and used the range A21:C21 for Biles B's Country, Name, and ID data. That way you can easily see which pieces need edited to be addressed for File B when you copy the formula into File A.

The formula for cell C1, then to be copied and pasted down the column as needed is:

```
=FILTER(  $C$21:$C$30, $A$21:$A$30 & "|" & $B$21:$B$30 = A1 & "|" & B1)
```

First `FILTER()` looks through C21:C30 for values that match the row-by-row pairs of values from columns A & B. Notice you can use a range for each set (A21:A30 and B21:B30) so you can search the whole set of B-Country+B-Name pairs. Excel creates an internal array of them and compares your "match this or these" value that is to the right of the equal sign (A1, B1). Being able to use ranges for the "match these" makes this work.

You'll notice the `"|"` stuck between the Country and Name values. That is so that any coincidental lettering at the Country end and Name beginning doesn't cause wrong matches. Like, say, you have "horse" and "hors" in the first column, and "cho" and "echo" in the second. Without a separator ("delimiter" could be said), those would join together to give "horsecho" and "horsecho"... the same value to lookup for different inputs. This is one way to avoid that kind of error.

`FILTER()` finds a match, reads the corresponding B-ID value, and returns it to the formula. That's all there is to it for your needs.

However, `FILTER()` would actually return **ALL** the matches that existed so if the File B list were not so surely perfect in the respect that it has ONLY one instance of each Country+Name pairing, `FILTER()` would return all matches found which would lead to a `SPILL` error nowadays, and in earlier versions of Excel, only report the first one, which might be fine, might not, but in either case, would give no actual sign of there being other, possibly different ones. So keep that in mind if using this approach for different lookups in the future.

`FILTER()` is a very useful function. This use is limited, or perhaps I should say a "precise" use of it. Ordinarily, one would be expecting more than one result and that would be a main point in using it.

The difficulty with, say, `VLOOKUP()` is creating its lookup range. It can be done, and helper columns are a fine tool for it. (Don't look down on helper columns the way many do. Not only can they often be deleted or cleared after use, if an ad hoc need arises, but one can have a "scratch worksheet" (or "helper worksheet") hidden somewhere out of the way on which one does all his helper column work so the columns take no space on output pages and working pages, as well as simply not being part of the user's experience.) Since `FILTER()` EXPECTS ranges, it is from the start the easy way to handle this kind of difficulty.